# Elite: Dangerous Horizons - What does the Data Link Scanner (on SRV) do to turrets?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I used the Data Link Scanner on a hostile settlement turret, and the interface implied it was doing something, but there was no effect I could observe. Obviously deactivating turrets with the DLS instead of shooting them would be overpowered, and yet it's possible to target and scan them. There's no mention of using it on turrets anywhere online - or am I a bit slow, and it's just possible to scan anything you can target (with no effect)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Data Link Scanner](http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Data_Link_Scanner?comments_page=1) can be used to hack/interact/scan different types of turrets. You can also receive data from the scans, much like scanning enemy ships.

The comments of the linked wiki article goes into some detail with troubleshooting if you're having trouble getting it to work. Some of the controls for the SRV arent bound by default, and you may need to bind the data scanner to a key press, fire group, both, or neither (depending on your control scheme).

Comment: Yes, it works fine on the data point things, giving data I can sell, as well as on the mining extractors, revealing their contents — it just didn't seem to have any observable effect on the turrets

Comment: @Toadfish oh sorry, i understand now. I've personally never had a "Hack" opportunity either, just scanning, but i took that to mean some turrets may be able to be turned friendly or something via the DLS.

Comment: that's what I was hoping, however upon reflexion it'd be much too easy, like a few seconds of scanning vs like a minute of shooting would be a total no-brainer. A more balanced effect would be lowering their shields (but they don't have shields) or maybe stopping them temporarily to make it safer to destroy them, but it didn't do either of those either, sadly.